# How to prevent form submitting every time the page is refreshed?

Tags: php, html, forms, page-refresh

I'm developing a website with HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP. This website has a page with a POST form. Every time the user submits this form, the input data is stored in a database and it is working just fine. The problem is that when I refresh the page, the form is automatically submited and the last user input is stored in the database once again.

Can you tell me how can I make the form be exclusively submited only when the user presses the submit button? (and not when the page is refreshed)
Thanks for the atention.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault